# Zend-Framework View Helper - Is it specific view related?

Tags: zend-framework, view, helper

When we create a view helper, on a Zend application, will that helper be available for ALL the views or, should we somehow tell that THAT view helper is available to a specific view?
What if, on the view folder "something", we have more then one file ? Any of those files can call it?

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Comment: The view helper is available on all views.

Comment: Thank you.:) If you answer with that, I can give you the points. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a view helper, the framework will look within the paths defined via `$view->addHelperPath()`. Typically, such a call will include a pseudo-namespace as well as a path:

`$view->addHelperPath('My/View/Helper', 'My_View_Helper_');`

Then when you call a view helper in a layout or a view script:

`<?php echo $this->someHelper() ?>`

The framework will do a LIFO search, appending the prefixes (in the above case: `'My_View_Helper_'`) to the classname `'SomeHelper'` and then attempting to load the file defined by the `addHelperPath()` mapping.

In the default setup, the framework pre-loads the Zend view helpers by calling:

`$view->addHelperPath('Zend/View/Helper', 'Zend_View_Helper_');`

which is why you can use all the Zend-provided view helpers right out of the box.

Since all this processing is independent of which view script is making the call, it will work in any view script. [There are actually some issues associated to calling view helpers defined in other modules, but that's a separate issue.]